# Java remove duplicate objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have a very lengthy ArrayList comprised of objects some of them however, are undoubtedly duplicates.  What is the best way of finding and removing these duplicates.  Note:  I have written a boolean-returning compareObjects() method.

Comment: Add all the objects of your arrayList in a Set (LinkedHashSet will maintain the order of the original list, otherwise HashSet will do it fine, just make sure that you override equals and hashcode for your class). See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: any particular kind?  I assume Set prevents duplicates?  I'm a beginner.

Comment: Refer to [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Answer (score 34):

### Example

```
List<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
Set<String> titles = new HashSet<String>();

for( Item item : originalList ) {
    if( titles.add( item.getTitle() )) {
        result.add( item );
    }
}
```

### Reference

[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)
[Java Data Structures](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Java_Collections_Overview)

Comment: A `HashSet` prevents duplicates.

Comment: @JoshM _All_ sets should prevent duplicates.  The first line from [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is "A collection that contains no duplicate elements."

Comment: LinkedHashSet should be used in this case to items order

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I thought a `TreeSet` still allowed duplicates. Oh, my bad, nvm you're right.

Comment: @JoshM the differente between a common `Set` e.g. `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` and a `SortedSet` e.g. `TreeSet` is that `Set` use `equals` and `hashCode` methods to compare object equality while `SortedSet` use `compareTo` or a `Comparator` for its elements. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16931990/1065197) for more info.

Comment: It seems strange that you would do it this way rather than what @ashes999 did. Both will work obviously but I think using a .contains() call is more clear as to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 9):

You mentioned writing a `compareObjects` method. Actually, you should override the `equals` method to return `true` when two objects are equal.

Having said that, I would just return a new list that contains unique elements from the original:

```
ArrayList<T> original = ...
List<T> uniques = new ArrayList<T>();
for (T element : original) {
  if (!uniques.contains(element)) {
    uniques.add(element);
  }
}
```

This only works if you override `equals`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642589/how-does-a-java-arraylist-contains-method-evaluate-objects) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

`Hashset` will remove duplicates. Example:

```
Set< String > uniqueItems = new HashSet< String >();
uniqueItems.add("a");
uniqueItems.add("a");
uniqueItems.add("b");
uniqueItems.add("c");
```

The set `"uniqueItems"` will contain the following : a, b, c